# how to access data from from controller in rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i created project scaffold that has one to many association with stage and stage scaffold has one to many association with task. in project#show action i want to access tasks on the basis of stage i am not able to do that.

projects_controller.rb(show#action)

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: {sub_tasks: {sub_sub_tasks: :sub_three_tasks}}}}).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages

    task_counter = 0
    @tasks = @stages.tasks  #(undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass )
    @tasks.each{|s| task_counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 0 || s.status == 2}
  end
```

Comment: So you want to get all the `tasks` belonging to the stages of the `@project`, right?

Comment: @MarekLipka yes, in project controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `includes` makes no sense whatsoever since you're only getting one `Project` instance.

If you want to get the `Stage#tasks` of all the records in `@stages`, it would be something like this:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@stages = @project.stages
@tasks = Task.where(stage_id: @stages.ids)
```

Comment: Hi thanks, i have used ```includes ``` relation in  in project show#action view. to access data from different model easily. and ```@tasks = Task.where(stage_id: @stages.ids)``` resolved my current problem.

Comment: Using `includes` this way doesn't make any sense, doesn't help in anything. Just remove it, I guarantee it will still work as  you expect.

Comment: hey if i have to do same thing in project#index action how can i do that? i am getting problem in that. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60562163/how-to-print-pending-tasks-count-for-each-entries-in-rails-application]